# PharData zip to include empty folders

Tags: php, compression, phar

I am zipping entire server content(for backup purposes) via php / PharData:

```
$phar = new PharData(SYS_ROOT.'/project.zip');
$phar->buildFromDirectory(SYS_ROOT.'/');
```

SYS_ROOT is constant defining path to web root (. dot in this case). Everything works fine except for missing empty folders in the resulting zip. The folders are necessary.

I tought about Phar::addEmptyDir, but that would require another iteration through the folders to determine which are empty. Tried recursivedirectoryiterator to no avail(also skipped empty folders) as well :(

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this but looking at the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.buildfromdirectory.php) it says the following:

`Phar::buildFromDirectory — Construct a phar archive from the files within a directory.`

Which means that it is behaving as expected. However I think you could use [buildFromIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.buildfromiterator.php) and then also [compress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.compress.php) since this is for backups I think I'd go with that one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however the iterator also skips empty folders as I mentioned :(

Comment: Did you pass the flag `FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME` to the iterator? Maybe that fixes it.